# Loop statement inside if else statement

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach, codeigniter-3

i want to show all rows using loop in a table, but if there is no data available i want to echo some text there.
i am using codeigniter. i want to use loop inside if statement and in else i will echo any text when there will be no data.

here is the code

```
<?php 
$nextdate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+3 day"));
$this->db->order_by('tourdateID', 'ASC');
$this->db->where('tourid', $blogres[0]['tourid']);
$this->db->where('start >=', $nextdate); 
$subs = $this->db->get('tour_date')->result_array();

$i = 1;

foreach($subs as $sub){?>
    <div class="row priceRow priceRowReg  filter_12  guaranteedFlag">
        <div class="eq-pr2 small-4 medium-4 large-4 columns pad-lft-20">
            <div class="tcircle amber"></div><a class="date drk" rel="nofollow" href="#"><?php echo date('d M, Y', strtotime($sub['start'])); ?> - <?php echo date('d M, Y', strtotime($sub['end'])); ?></a>

        </div>

        <div class="eq-pr2 small-3 medium-3 large-3 columns cnt bld"><?php 

        $this->db->where('tourdateID',$sub['tourdateID']);
        $booking = $this->db->count_all_results('book_tour');                    
        $availibility = $sub['total_capacity'] - $booking;


        ?><?= $availibility; ?> Seats left</div>
        <div class="eq-pr2 small-3 medium-3 large-3 columns cnt pad-rgt-20"><a class="inl bld f19 wht wrBCol3 colLinkPad showinfo" rel="nofollow" href="<?=base_url();?>bookings/step1/<?= $blogres[0]['tourid'];?>/<?= $sub['tourdateID']?>">Book Now</a> </div>

    </div>

<? } ?>
```

Comment: What problem exactly are you having? It sounds like you know exactly what you want to do, have just haven't _done_ it.

Comment: it had been solved, it was just curly barces missing in my code after if statement, i got confused with braces of loop.

Comment: Next time, please do include your attempt within the question.  It likely could have been closed rather quickly as a typo.

Comment: yes you are right and thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But the `if` around the loop:

```
if (count($subs) > 0) {
    foreach ($subs as $sub) {?>
        ...
    <?php } 
} else { ?>
    <div> No data available </div>
<?php }
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. i just missed a braces of if tag.